# How to configure keycloak to protect all services hosted on a URL

Tags: go, postman, keycloak

I have multiple services running on localhost:8080.
For e.g:

a) `GET  localhost:8080/idtest/{id}`

b) `POST localhost:8080/idtest`

and to test them I use POSTMAN.

I want to protect these services by keycloak authentication when they are triggered. Hence, I got the keycloak server installed, created realm,client and rolemapping.

Is there a possibility to add authentication in general to all API's with the same root path just at one place?

Using Golang for implementation.

In keycloak client page:

**Base URL:** `localhost:8080`

**Redirect URL:** `localhost:8080/test`

I have followed [this procedure](https://tutorialedge.net/golang/go-oauth2-tutorial/)  in my localhost client.

As per it, when I am running `localhost:8080` on my browser, I get redirected to `http://localhost:8080/test` and I get below json:

```
  {
    "OAuth2Token": {

    "access_token": "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1Ni",
    "token_type": "bearer",
    "refresh_token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIs",
    "expiry": "2019-07-16T17:41:43.4884786-04:00"

    },
    "IDTokenClaims": null
  }
```

Now when I am using POSTMAN with my header type authorization - bearer "accesstoken retrived from above JSON" for

1) `http://localhost:8080` I again get HTML for keyclaok login,
but when I am using browser to hit `http://localhost:8080` it is redirecting me to `localhost:8080/test` page.

How can I test it from POSTMAN? What am I doing wrong?

2) `http://localhost:8080/idtest/12345` this service runs seamless irrespective of access token. I want to know how can I add this under the umbrella of same authentication ? I read about single sign on for multiple clients but these services belong to same client.

I tried adding them as resources under authorization tab of client. Do I need to make any changes in the code as well ? How can I do it ?

Comment: what is Access Type set for your client?  may be you need understand more about the Access types here https://www.keycloak.org/docs/6.0/server_admin/#_clients.

Comment: Access Type in my case is Confidential.

Comment: I recommend to use https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-gatekeeper, which has quite complex features and then you can keep your app simple (without any oidc logic)